# Regex on variable names in R (reformatting dataset)

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I'm working with yelp dataset. Variable names are in the form "day.hour". So `Fri.4` means Friday 4am and `Fri.22` means Friday at 10pm, and the variable value is the number of checkins at that time.

I want to create a plot where I have 7 lines. Each line represents a day of the week and each line shows how the average checkins are trending by the hour of the day. So each line connects 24 points, and I have 7 lines.

Any help?

I would use `dplyr` but can't figure out how to get all the Monday variables together and the Tuesday variables together etc because the names are like `Tue.01`, `Tues.02`, etc.... How do I do operations on the strings?

How my current dataset is formatted:
my dataset is 1x168 (each variable is the date.time)

```
Fri.0 114.35897
Sat.0 154.92308
Sun.0 153.96154
Wed.0 93.92308
Fri.1 124.29487
Sat.1 168.07692
Thu.1 105.96154
Wed.1 101.85897
Sat.2 175.00000
Sun.2 157.48718
Thu.2 105.97436
Wed.2 97.08974
Fri.3 108.46154
Sun.3 145.24359
```

[image]

Comment: Please show your plotting code so people can help.

Comment: i have not plotted anything.... im stuck trying to group all the fridays together and thursdays together and so on for each day...

Comment: Can you show an example of the format of the final dataframe you need to plot? I know with `dplyr` you can use group_by()` to get things in groups, or split the day into two columns; the first containing the day only and the second the time, which would make group_by() easier

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple pipe directly into `ggplot`, there is no need to `group_by` the weekdays, the `ggplot2` aesthetic `aes(colour = .)` will do the grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

dh %>%
  mutate(Weekday = str_extract(day.hour, "^[[:alpha:]]{3}"),
         Day = as.integer(str_extract(day.hour, "[[:digit:]]*$"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = value, colour = Weekday)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
dh <- read.table(text = "
Fri.0 114.35897
Sat.0 154.92308
Sun.0 153.96154
Wed.0 93.92308
Fri.1 124.29487
Sat.1 168.07692
Thu.1 105.96154
Wed.1 101.85897
Sat.2 175.00000
Sun.2 157.48718
Thu.2 105.97436
Wed.2 97.08974
Fri.3 108.46154
Sun.3 145.24359                 
")

names(dh) <- c("day.hour", "value")
```